# Sticky Footer Issue (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, footer, spacing, sticky

Hello i'm trying to implement a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page no matter the content size here 22twenty.com/wordpress and its not working the footer is for some reason sitting at the bottom of the gradient wrap not the page, i used this tutorial: http://www.wordimpressed.com/wordpress/put-a-css-sticky-footer-in-your-wordpress-theme/

If you need anymore info just ask
Thanks

Denver

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with your page and CSS I found you hadn't quite completed the tutorial based on the link provided.  The following is what was needed to be changed:

1. Move the footer tag outside of the container div.
2. Remove the margin line from the footer CSS rule.

These two things will move the footer to the bottom right of the page.

Comment: Does that mean im missing a close div somewhere?
Thanks

Comment: http://22twenty.com/wordpress/artists/  if you go there you will see that even after i did what you say the footer doesnt stay to the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, hadn't been back for a while.  I take it that you aren't doing it anymore as the mainpage is now different and the /artists page doesn't exist.